# Describe the joint probability between X and Y.

Tags: probability, statistics

Let X be a random variable with possible values {-2,-1,0,1,2}, with probability 1/5 each, and Y random variable with Y = X^2. Describe their joint probability(in a table) and find the correlation of X and Y.

I don't know how to start with this question.

Comment: Welcome to Maths SE. For something like this, I think google should be your first port of call. Correlation is described on wikipedia. Once you've given it a go, come back and check your answer if you like.

Answer (score 1):

For each value of $X$, you know that $Y$ can have only a single value (which is $X^2$). Therefore you can describe the joint probability distribution of $(X, Y)$:

$$\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|c|}\hline
  & X = -2 & X = -1 & X = 0 & X = +1 & X = +2 \\\hline\hline
Y = 0 & 0  & 0  & \frac 15 & 0 & 0 \\\hline
Y = 1 & 0  & \frac 15 & 0 & \frac 15 & 0 \\\hline
Y = 4 & \frac 15 & 0 & 0 & 0 & \frac 15 \\\hline
\end{array}$$

You know that the sum of the probabilities of each column must equal to $\frac 15$ since it is the *marginal* distribution of $X$, which you know. In every cell $(X, Y)$ such that $Y \neq X^2$, the joint probability is $0$, therefore the remaining cell must have probability $\frac 15$.

Now that you have the joint distribution, you need to find the correlation defined as:

$$\text{Corr}(X, Y) = \frac {\text{Cov}(X, Y)}{\sigma_X\sigma_Y},$$

where $\text{Cov}(X, Y) = \mathbb E\left[(X-\mathbb E[X])(Y - \mathbb E[Y])\right]$ is the covariance, and $\sigma$ is the standard deviation.

$$\mathbb E[X] = 0 \quad \text{ and } \quad \mathbb E[Y] = 0 \times \frac 15 + 1 \times \frac 25 + 4 \times \frac 25 = 2$$.

based on this, can you find $\sigma_X, \sigma_Y, \text{Cov}(X, Y)$ and conclude?

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought every cell should be 1/5 before , so that I didn't know how to continue.